# How to check we are in a specific page in Flutter integration or not?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am writing Integration test for my Flutter app.
at the start of app depends on that the user have logged in it can be on
HomePage() or OnBoardingPage()

how can I find out in which page it is in Integration test

```
  testWidgets('test onBoarding phase', (tester) async {
app.main();
await tester.pumpAndSettle();

 final homePageFinder = find.byKey(
  const Key("homePage"),
);
final onBoardingFinder = find.byKey(
  const Key("onBoarding"),
);
)}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [`tester.any()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_test/WidgetController/any.html) method,which checks if finder exists in the tree,to use it you can for example:

```
bool isHomePage = tester.any(homePageFinder);
bool isOnBoarding = tester.any(onBoardingFinder);
```